# Azure HTTP POST requests for an access token from Power BI

Tags: azure-active-directory, http-post, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to get azure AD app access token from Power BI power query with HTTP POST requests?

HTTP POST requests:

```
//request url
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token

//header
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

//request body
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=625bc9f6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
client_secret=bCBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
resource=api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#example

Ok, its looks pretty simple and it works nicely with `Postman` or `python` request and shows a success response with json data.
Now what my problem is I want to through this request with `Power BI power query` here is my `power query`

```
let
  apiUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token",
    body = "{
    ""grant_type"": ""client_credentials"",
    ""client_id"": ""625bc9f6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
    ""client_secret"": ""bCBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
    ""resource"": ""api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""
    }",

  Source = Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
           Content=Text.ToBinary(body)]),
  FormatAsJson = Json.Document(Source)
in
    FormatAsJson
```

But it said Bad request

```
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/61ed5503-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token' (400): Bad Request
```

What am I missing or why it says bad request?
Is it the reason that its not a `REST API`?
or is there any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: It's a Bad Request, so it could be some mistake in the construction of the url. Can you check that using Fiddler? Compare the request you make with Power Query and a working one, using a tool like Postman.

Comment: thanks @Dreekun for your suggest , I will try it and let you know what happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, actually there is some extra terms that i had to add and also a silly mistake by my self, 
The correct query

```
let
  apiUrl = "https://login.windows.net/61xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token",
    body = [
          client_id="3728xxxxxxxxxxxxxx5",
          grant_type="client_credentials",
          client_secret="bxxxxxxxxxxxxh",
          resource="api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5"
],

  Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers = [Accept = "application/json"],
 Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(body))]))
in
Source
```