# Power BI REST API Usage data in Power Query/Power BI

Tags: rest, https, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to get usage data from Power BI into Power BI desktop in order to create an admin report. The report will show the usage of the different reports in Power BI.

In order to get this data I am using the Power BI REST APIs. Specifically calls such as:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets -- To get datasets
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/apps?$top={$top} -- To get apps
```

To get datasets in Power Query I can then write:

```
let
Source = Json.Document(
Web.Contents(
"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer MYKEY"]]))
in Source
```

This does retrieve the datasets. However the key used is taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/apps-get-apps-as-admin#code-try-0

This link allows a user to try the API, which gives you a temporary key. In order to get a refreshable token/key, another call must be made to the API. In order to make this call I have created an application in Azure which has been granted rights by our admin. In order to retrieve the refreshable token, I have written this in Power Query (by using [Azure HTTP POST requests for an access token from Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632458/azure-http-post-requests-for-an-access-token-from-power-bi)):

```
  () =>
let
  apiUrl = "https://login.windows.net/MY TENANT ID/oauth2/token",
    body = [
          client_id="My Client ID",
          grant_type="client_credentials",
          client_secret="My Client Secret",
          resource="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
],

  Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers = [Accept = "application/json"],
 Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(body))]))
in
Source
```

This call is successful and returns me the following (Photo):
[image: Refreshable Token]

The natural progression would then be to paste the generated access token into my first query, but this gives me an access error. *"Expression.Error: Access to the resource is forbidden."* When changing the data sources settings from anonymous to Windows I get another error message: *"Expression.Error" The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously..."*

Any ideas on what to do in order to get the data into Power BI would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not the answer you are looking for but my team was attempting to do the very same thing and found the only way to get this to work was to add some form of data store between PBI admin logs and the PBI dataset. We use CSV's and a sql database but an Azure Job runs on a schedule and collects the data and stores it locally, then PBI reads that stored data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you can build admin reports from the Power BI Service data using the Power BI REST API Connector from Github ([link](https://github.com/migueesc123/PowerBIRESTAPI)). Then you can connect to the service directly from PBI Desktop, without dealing yourself with OAuth and/or AAD authentication. The connector has some limitations, but it was very useful for our reporting.

I don't know if you can install this custom connector in the Power BI Service, but it works perfectly in Power BI Desktop.